# Заполнение векторов. C++

Tags: c++, вектор, векторы

Захотел я заполнить вектор при помощи итераторов. Получился вот такой вот код:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    vector<int> vec2;
    for (vector<int>::iterator i = vec2.begin(); i!=vec2.end(); i++)
    {
        vec2.insert(i,n);
        n++;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том что ничего не заполняется. В чем проблема?

Comment: В том, что вектор пуст и проверка сразу дает false?

Comment: Когда я выделял память при помощи resize() или reserve() ситуация была такая же.

Comment: `reserve` ничего не меняет, потому что в векторе все еще будет 0 элементов. `resize` сделал бы так, что цикл выполнялся, но остается другая проблема: `insert` "инвалидирует" итератора `i` (после чего им нельзя пользоваться), это раз. А два - даже если это проигнориовать, получается бесконечный цикл.

Comment: А **сколько** вы хотите внести в вектор значений, можно узнать?

Comment: Пожалуйста выберите один из двух предоставленных ответов, как "Правильный ответ", если конечно он таковым является :). Для этого нужно нажать на галочку слева от понравившегося вам ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите заполнить вектор при помощи итератора, то нужно воспользоваться операцией разыменования итератора.

Вот пример:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    //Размер вектора
    int size_vector = 3;
    //Выделим сразу память под size_vector элементов
    vector<int> vec2(size_vector);
    //Пройдемся по всему вектору
    for (vector<int>::iterator i = vec2.begin(); i != vec2.end(); i++)
    {
        //Операция разыменования позволяет изменить значение
        //элементу на который указывает итератор
        *i = n;
        n++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Так же вектор можно заполнить при помощи функции `insert` или `push_back`, но эти функции не меняют значения, а добавляют новые значения.

Если вам так нужно, то вот пример:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    int size_vector = 3;
    vector<int> vec2;

    vector<int>::iterator i = vec2.end();
    for (int j = 0; j < size_vector; ++j) {
        vec2.insert(i, n);
        n++;
        i = vec2.end();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Но последний пример он больше для того, чтобы показать итератор, на самом деле проще убрать полностью переменную `i` и писать вот такую строчку:

```
vec2.insert(vec2.end(), temp);
```

Answer (score -1):

Хоть это странно выглядит заполнять так как у вас и также неверно, но я могу предложить минимальный набор правок, без `.insert(...)`, чтобы похожий на ваш код заработал, тоже с итераторами (для примера заполняю 25 элементов в векторе):

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://godbolt.org/z/5ha5z3)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    vector<int> vec2(25);
    for (vector<int>::iterator i = vec2.begin(); i != vec2.end(); ++i)
        *i = n++;
    for (auto x: vec2)
        cout << x << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
```

---

Либо вариант заполнения с `.insert(...)` ниже:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://godbolt.org/z/EK8P89)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    vector<int> vec2;
    for (int j = 0; j < 25; ++j)
        vec2.insert(vec2.end(), n++);
    for (auto x: vec2)
        cout << x << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
```

Comment: Извините, а чем ваш код отличается от моего?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Когда я его написал то вашего ответа ещё не было, когда нажал послать готовый ответ то одновременно система сообщила что в это время ваш ответ появился, в итоге я не удалял свой т.к. написал уже, ну чей выберут тот выберут.

Comment: Я увидел ваш ответ и подумал, что одновременно нажали. Но как то изменять ответ добавляя идею из моего ответа, как то не красиво уже. Ну ладно дело ваше.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Я всегда любые ответы дополняю поэтапно, т.е. минимальную базу пишу вначале, постю, а потом все остальные идеи что в голове были дополняю. Вариант с `.insert(...)` у меня в голове конечно был, т.к. это супер очевидное решение. Как говорю я запостил минимальное решение и начал писать остальные, точнее одно с инсертом. Просто очевидное insert-базированное решение не может быть чьей то исключительной идеей, которое нужно где то почитать и скопировать, оно всем понятно, и у меня в голове оно тоже было. Просто раз я пост уже написал то решил его всеми идеями из головы дополнить.

Comment: Сейчас ни на кого не говорю, но вот просто как идея. Можно выкладывать минимальный код, а потом смотреть идеи у других ответов,  добавлять в свой код и говорить, что было это в голове. Еще раз повторю это не про вас. Про `insert` это понятно что очевидное решение. Просто вы уже ответили и как вы сказали увидели мой ответ, и начали дополнять свой ответ похожим кодом и идеями, хотя могли уже остановится на том, что есть. В общем ладно, не суть. Хмм я заметил, что у вас всегда на все есть "отмазка"

Comment: @ПавелЕриков А я заметил что вы любите часами со всеми спорить и учить.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков То что ещё ответов не было и я потратил какое то время на написание и оформление кода и ответа и тестов, уже означает что я не просто так потратил время и не хочу просто мусор написать. А раз уже начал писать, то я всё что у меня было в голове дописываю.Даже если кто то одновременно запостил своё решение.Я не вижу смысла просто остановиться и удалить то ради чего старался.Или остановиться и не дополнить тем что уже хотел. Ничего я из вашего ответа не копировал.Это если был бы какой то гениальный алгоритм на 300 строк то конечно очевидно что было бы копирования,а так очевидная идея

Comment: Да хорошо хорошо, я не писал что вы у меня скопировали что либо, вы просто написали тоже самое, в чем смысла мало. Я так же не просил вас удалять ничего, просто написал что вы **могли** остановится и не тратить силы на тот же код, что у меня. И ничему я вас не учил и сейчас не спорю с вами. Просто поинтересовался. Я даже написал, "Ну ладно дело ваше" на этот моменте уже должно закончиться все.

Comment: Зачем спорить, если ни один из ответов не отвечает на  конкретный  вопрос: "В чем проблема?", а отвечает на совершенно другой вопрос, которого тут нет, и, к тому  же  настолько тривиален, что вряд ли кого то заинтересует.